# NHibernate & session-per-conversation in AJAX scenario: manual flush needed?

Tags: ajax, nhibernate, session, flush

we are facing a very strange problem with our application, until now i see no option to solve the problem:

The application uses NHibernate (3.1.x) in an session-per-conversation architecture, meaning at start/end of each ASP/IIS request a NHibernate session with a new transaction is opened/closed + flushed/committed.

Now, we have a mailbox in the application including a simple mailgrid:
The mailgrid is populated first time when a user enters the mailbox (start-Request creates a new NHibernate session/transaction, loads stuff from DB, on end-Request the session is closed)

The problem occurs at the deletion of a mail:

(1)
the deletion of mails does not happen via a full page-reload/refresh, instead it calls a webservice which returns the new rendered HTML grid after a message is deleted.
This webservice deletes a mail by doing a simple

```
T_Mails m = T_Mails.GetMailByID( 12345678 );
m.Status = MailStatusDeleted;
NHibernateSession.Update( m );
```

(2)
After this call to update the mail, the same function also re-renders the updated mailgrid - it does this by querying for the last 5 rows in table T_Mails (one mailbox page contains only 5 rows!); then, this is the current content of the mailbox for a given user.

The problem now is:
Since both of these calls occur in the same function of the webservice (and thus in the same session/transaction scope), the mail we want to delete (in step 1), is not deleted since the updated status from NHibernateSession.Update( m ) does not reach the database.

If i open the table via MSSQL ManagementStudio while a debugging session i can see that the status of the mail is not persited to database.

My simple solution for this problem would be:
Doing a manual NHibernateSession.Flush() call between updating the mail and reloading the content from the table?
But: this would break the session-per-conversation pattern, since NhibernateSession.Flush() is/should occuring at the end of each request - it's not ought to be called manually somewhere in the running request.

Otherwise i'm really stuck.

Comment: How do you query for the last 5 rows after you update the mail status to deleted?

Comment: `code` 
ICriteria ic = CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(V_Mailbox));
ic.Add(Expression.Not(Expression.Eq("ReceiverStatusID", T_Mails.StatusDeleted))); 
ic.List<T_Mails>(); `code` while CurrentSession is the same session which was used to update the message. One additional note: i do not delete the mail in the table, this was not exactly: i make the mail invisible for the front-end by setting a flag "delete=1" in the mail row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make 2 ajax calls - first one to delete an item and second one to refresh list when first query will be finished. Please make sure that you are making calls in same order. Below is sample code using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Mail/Delete',
    data: { mailId: someId },
    success: function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Mail/Refresh',
            success: function (data) {
                //here you should put new list into list container
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Xelibrion, thanks for your input. YES, making two calls would be "the final-end solution", i thought already about that - but, hell, am i the only one who faces this problem? is there **really** no other solution?

Comment: It is the simplest and obvious solution. Do you really need another one?

Comment: Technically, you are right: deleting and redrawing the mail-grid are two different actions, so this solution will work, sure - but i hoped there would be another solution which does not build on spawning a second request (and thus a second session+transaction), even if this will fit perfectly into our technical paradigm. What i don't understand, is, why NHibernate does not recognize the updated flag even if its the **same** session i'm using to redraw the grid - i thought this is will work out with this pattern (why else should one be interested in using same session? :-)  )

Comment: NHibernate does not use 1st level cache for queries - it works only for Get/Load methods.

Comment: No no, sorry: my comment was not about worries, that caching may not be used - it was just a "pure technical" comment, that i looked forward to "use as **LESS** sessions/transactions as possible", this is why i headed for another solution. So, if you, too, mean, the best solution is to just do two calls (one for deleting, afterwards[directly] another one for redrawing the mail-grid), i think i will go for that solution. But i'm still hoping anyone has another idea than doing doing two calls... This is why i said: "is **really** nobody else facing this isue?", because its very common, i think?

Comment: I suppose anybody, who facing this issue, makes 2 calls because it is not only very simple solution without side effects (you don't have to deal with concurrency and etc.), but it also what single responsibility principle is about.

Comment: Xelib., thanks, your input is highly appreciated. I think, you conviced me in this special case. But please let me extend this to another dummy-question: am i right -> _this_ is typical requirement to any application (i mean "deleting an object and afterwards refreshing a grid"), so you mean **every** of the "big applications" does it _that_ way? I mean, doing two calls (with two sessions+transactions) is really a hit, because it means "100% increase" of session consumption - and all of them are working like _that_?? hell, and i thought i'm the only tinkerer in this discipline :-))

Comment: It depends on application. Some of them simulate real deletion by client scripting (using javascipt), some refresh list. One database call on denormalized storage/NoSQL database is not performance hit, especially you have a lot of database servers and your app has good architecture.